# How do I get into 3D Java game development?

Tags: java, 3d

I have learned how to make a 2D game in Java using Eclipse and processing but I am not sure how to do 3D game development. I have tried looking up examples of how to do this but I have not found any useful ones.

Answer (score 1):

To create 3D graphics in java you will need to use [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/)(OpenGL wrapper) or similar.

For getting started I recommend to look at these:

- [LWJGL.org/guide](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide)
- [LearnOpenGL.com](http://learnopengl.com/)
- [Youtube.com/ThinMatrix](https://www.youtube.com/user/ThinMatrix/videos)

These helped me getting started, without even prior 2D experience, so I'm sure this will be easy.

If you don't want to make your own engine you can also take a look at [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/).